# Different properties files on the same server

Tags: java, tomcat, war

We have a database library that gets the connection information (user, host, etc) from a properties file. This file can be a `config.properties` file located in the classpath, or next to the execution jar or can be passed as an argument `-Dproperties=/path/to/myConfig.properties`.

We also have several applications that use this library, so each one has its own config.properties file used in its own execution.

But now I'm creating two web applications that use the same library. So, if I deploy them in Tomcat (war file), I have two options (to my knowledge):

1.- Include each config inside the WAR file. But with this, every time I need to tweak something in the `config.properties` I'll have to repack the war.

2.- Pass the `-Dproperties` parameter as an execution argument of Tomcat. But different war deployments will have to share the same properties file.

Is there a way around this?

Can I pass the `-D` argument to a specific deployment in Tomcat (or any other server)?

PS: This is one of the scenarios we have, but is not constraint to database connection info. We have other libraries that get parameters through `config.properties` file.

**EDIT**: I *want* to be able to have different `config.properties` file for each deployment. Not the same properties shared among them.

I think I found a way around using self contained webserver inside the application, like Jetty.

Comment: Can you modify the shared library which loads the properties?  If yes, add support for an optional property prefix.  For example, war 1 uses prefix "app1", and war 2 uses prefix "app2".  In the shared properties file: `app1.database.url=...` and `app2.database.url=...`.

Comment: Yes, I can modify the library. The thing is, the library is not specific for the web apps (other java projects may use it), and the number of web apps may grow, so if I understood your approach, it will be tailored to the "consumers" webapps. @AndrewS

Comment: Yes - the consumer of the shared library would need a method to set the prefix or inject an instance with the prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for my problem is using an embedded web server in my application. In my case, I'm using Jetty.

Now I pack my application as an executable jar and pass the system parameters as `-D` arguments and they live inside the instance of the application.
Like this:

```
java -Dproperties=config.properties -jar java_app_with_embedded_server.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

We've a similar requirement in which we share a common property file between different applications deployed into JBoss EAP server.

In $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf file you can add configuration file path as below:

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DCONFIG_LOCATION=/external/config/configuration.properties"

Start the server with above specified property and within your application you can read this property file with apache commons-configuration api as below:

```
 try {
                props = new PropertiesConfiguration(System.getProperty("CONFIG_LOCATION"));
                FileChangedReloadingStrategy strategy = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
                // Delay 30s
                // strategy.setRefreshDelay(30000);
                props.setReloadingStrategy(strategy);

            } catch (ConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

With this reload strategy you can change your properties while your server is running. Also you can specify the interval after which all properties specified in the external file needs to be refreshed within your application without bouncing it. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment variable whose value will be the path where the properties file are located. Later use this environment variable  will creating bean for property placeholder config.

for UNIX, you can add in your bash profile file

```
export CONF_DIR=/path/to/conf
```

And in spring context file, add this

```
<context:property-placeholder
  location="file:///${CONF_DIR}/path/myConfig1.properties,
  file:///${CONF_DIR}/path/myConfig2.properties"
  properties-ref="applicationDefaultProperties" ignore-resource-not-found="false"
  ignore-unresolvable="false"/>
```

So, when you want to change any thing in the properties file, you can change at one location, and then restart the application to load the new values in your app.

So, if your config file is this

```
db.user=username
db.password=password
```

Inside java class, you can use the keys as like this

```
@Value("${db.user")
private String username;

@Value("${db.password")
private String password;
```